# What is a Callback Handler?

Tags: javascript, callback

What is a Callback Handler in Javascript? I know what a callback function is, its a function that is called within a function or used as a parameter, that is called after the function is executed. A event handler is a script that is called when an 'event' is triggered. But what is a Callback Handler?

Google

```
this.save=function(filename,destination,callbackHandler,url,embedData){
  return this.componentObject.save(filename,destination,callbackHandler,url,embedData)
}
```

Comment: a callbackhandler is a callback function

Comment: It's just a variable name, someone called their callback, a `callbackHandler`.

Comment: `its a function that is called within a function or used as a parameter, that is called after the function is executed`  Close.  It can be called at any time.  It doesn't have to be at the end.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought that's why it was called "callback", and in the execution context it is called after the first function is called. I think you're right though not when it ends. I get what you're saying.

Comment: Nothing is stopping the callback function from being called at the end, though it often is. Sometimes, like in the case of array.forEach, the callback function is called multiple times.